# How to convert a string into a msoLanguageID

Tags: vba, powerpoint

**What I intend to do:**
I have a User Form where the user can select from a list of languages which is based on the possible languages in vba (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/office.msolanguageid). For this I have just removed the "msoLanguageID" part. Once the user has chosen the language and confirms, I would like to set the language for a selected / all slides.

**What I have done:**
I take the country name from the UserForm and add the "msoLanguageID" part back again (and remove any spaces in the string). So the name is exactly the same as in the list.

`Language_ID_String = "msoLanguageID" & SELECTED_LANGUAGE_WITHOUT_SPACES`

**The challenge:**
When setting the default language either an attribute of type "MsoLanguageID" or the language ID (integer) is required. So the string I have created won't work.

**Where I need help:**
Is there a way to convert the string into the type "MsoLanguageID"? Otherwise I assume I need to match the country back to the ID.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use a helper function that matches the country to the ID...

Comment: I could do that but conversion would be less effort and more efficient

Comment: Not sure there's any other viable option.

Comment: As @BigBen said there's no direct way to evaluate an enumeration value using a string. You can build a `Scripting.Dictionary` object (global or local to a helper function as @BigBen suggested). That will be very efficient. You can use the keys of this dictionary to populate your countries list in the userform

Comment: I do not understand **why** you need a string for what you want accomplishing. It is enough to the `Long/Integer` equivalent. It can be kept as a `String` and converted using `CLng` or `Int`.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses! The need was because I will only display the string in the user form and need to convert this either into an msoLanguageID or to map it to the ID number. I have decide to go with the latter as the conversion seems not to be possible.